# a4j:jsFunction not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am pretty new to JSF and RichFaces. I am using RichFaces 4.X and JSF 2.0. I have created a sample page, where my command button is called a a4j button, but it does not seem to be working. Here is my page. Can someone please help

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>My Registration Page</title>
    <link href="stylesheet/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.png" />

    <script language="javascript">
        function showProgressBar()
        {
            alert("its in show");
        }

        function hideProgressBar()
        {
            alert("its in hide");
        }
        </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="login" action="#{loginBean.validateUser}"
        onbegin="showProgressBar();"
        oncomplete="hideProgressBar();" />


    <div id="login-container">
        <div class="login-logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <f:view>
            <div id="loin-form">
                <h1>
                    Log in to your account or <a href="#">sign up</a> to Get Started
                </h1>
                <h:form>
                    <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}"
                        validator="#{loginBeanValidator.validateUserName}" required="true"
                        class="txtFld" />
                    <h:message for="userName"></h:message>
                    <h:inputSecret id="passWord" value="#{loginBean.passWord}"
                        validator="#{loginBeanValidator.validatePassword}" required="true"
                        class="pswrdFld" />
                    <h:message for="passWord"></h:message>
                    <p>
                        <a4j:commandLink id="forgotPasswordLink"
                            value="Forgot Your Password? " />
                        <a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In" action="login();"
                            styleClass="sign-btn" />
                    </p>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </f:view>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'Does not seem to be working' is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is in your command button

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In" action="login();"
     styleClass="sign-btn" />
```

The "action" attribute requires an EL expression to an action method that will be executed on the server when the button is pressed or a navigation rule. The purpose of a4j:jsFunction is to perform an ajax request from javascript call and the purpose of a4j:commandButton is to perform an ajax request when it's pressed. In your case you don't actually need a4j:jsFunction. Just remove it and put its the attributes on the a4j:commandButton like this:

```
 <a4j:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Sign In" 
    action="#{loginBean.validateUser}" onbegin="showProgressBar();"
    oncomplete="hideProgressBar();" styleClass="sign-btn" />
```